# Why does RDD to JSON remove the actual ordering of data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a JSON out of my pyspark dataframe. I see in my dataframe the data is sorted properly but when use toJSON, the sorting is not reflected in the JSON object. Could you please help

My Dataframe looks like this:

[image]

This is what happens when i use toJSON

[image]

Comment: A JSON object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. So there's no "order" in the JSON that DF has to pay any attention to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As spark works in distributed fashion and records are mostly distributed across worker nodes, when we perform collect data these records get transferred over the network to the driver node which need not to be in the same order. Ordering them over some key will involves more processing.